# How can I repeat a printf() every 1 second, but toggle it on and off with a specific user input?

Tags: c, while-loop, printing, toggle, sleep

I need to write a program that begins by accepting a user input, either "poke" or "quit". If the user types "poke", the program begins to print "Go Tigers" every 1 second, and at any time "poke" can be typed again to toggle the printing on or off. If "quit" is typed at any time, the program should exit.

Here's what I have so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#define MAXLEN 4

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLEN], input[MAXLEN];
    fgets(line, sizeof(line), stdin);
    sscanf(line, "%s", input);

    int flag = 0;

    if (input[0] == 'p')
        flag = 1;
    else if (input[0] == 'q')
        exit();

    while (flag == 1)
    {
        printf("Go Tigers\n");
        sleep(1);
    }
}
```

The printing is working fine, but I'm not sure how to allow input during the while loop to toggle it on/off. I think I have to use wait() and write another function, but I haven't had any luck with that yet.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One way is to install a timer (e.g. interrupt service routine) that does the printing.  Another way is to start a thread that does the output.  For either of these, it makes most sense for your `main` to handle the input stuff, and have your output driven on the side (either as a timer or thread).  Yet another way is to `fork` your program into two processes and have the child process do the output.  When the parent process wants to stop the output loop, it can simply kill the child process.

Comment: @paddy I think fork is what I needed! I'll give it a shot